# Java method using Strings

Tags: java, string, methods

please I need help with this method:

```
String d = ret.getData(); //I get the string using this
int ui;
ui = d.indexOf("=", d.indexOf("=")+1);
do{
int f=d.indexOf("=", ui+1 );
System.out.println(d.substring(ui+1, f-1));//Here I'm showing the results of my code
ui = ui + d.indexOf("=", ui);}
while ((d.indexOf("=") + ui)!= 0);
```

The String I have is this one:

```
!re
=.id=*1
=name=ether1
=mtu=1500
=l2mtu=1600
=mac-address=D4:CA:6D:37:44:26
=arp=enabled
=auto-negotiation=true
=full-duplex=true
=speed=100Mbps
=running=true
=slave=false
=disabled=false
```

And the results of my code are:

```
*1
ether1
l2mt
24:22
nin
```

And what I want to get is:

```
*1
ether1
1500
1600
D4:CA:6D:37:44:26
enabled
true
true
100Mbps
true
false
false
```

I need to get everything that is after the "="

Please help! Thanks

Comment: you can use the [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) method together with `substring()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner( ret.getData() );
scan.nextLine(); //skip the first line

While (scan.hasNextLine()){
     String s = scan.nextLine();
     int index = s.lastIndexOf("=");
     System.out.println(s.substring(index+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), with "=" as the delimiter. Simply run scanner.next() and read in each token as it comes :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `d.split("=")` method and get the latest value of the resulting array

Comment: Yeah, and print out the event values in the array since your data is  uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string with the help of string.split function  by `=`. It will return array of string. Now  in for loop increment it twice and display the output.

Answer (score 0):

A splitter would help and is the easiest and correct way of doing it. However if you want to touch your nose other way around or looking for an alternative then you can use Regular expression/Pattern matcher. :-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass test = new TestClass();


    String d = "=mtu=1500"; //I get the string using this
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(d);
    System.out.println(scan.nextLine().split("=")[2]);


}
```

This would print - 1500